# Cannot connect to remote debugger

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm not able to connect to Visual Studio remote debugger on remote machine (in the same network). The MSVSMON is running on the remote machine. When I try to list the process, there is a entry (in the remote machine) in the VS Remote Debugging Monitor saying the "username" connected. But the on the host, machine it times out and displays an error.

I'm running Windows Server 2012. Visual Studio 2010. x64.

Any leads on how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your firewall settings are correct? It seems that it's a connection problem. More on firewall configuration here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126350.aspx

Comment: Have you resolved this? Never forget to include the actual error!